# Super Noob Help ~ MouseEvent/Frame

Tags: java, mouseevent, frame

I just started getting into java a few weeks ago, and I have a little problem.  I have no experience in programming, and all I'm doing now is searching online for little tutorials and such.  I am currently playing around with some events with awt, and found myself a little java class online I could mess around with.

Anyway, I am trying to use the MouseEvent function/interface to do something when the mouse is moved/clicked/pressed, specifically inside a frame.  In this case, ClickCounter() is the frame class.

```
public ClickCounter() {
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ae) {
        clicks++;
        String s = Integer.toString(clicks);
        objTextField.setText("Clicks:" + s);
    }
    ClickCounter.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    ClickCounter.setSize(2000, 2000);
    ClickCounter.setVisible(true);
    TextField objTextField = new TextField(100);
    objTextField.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
    objTextField.setText("Click here and I will count the number of times you click");
    ClickCounter.add(objTextField);
}
```

It's a mess, I know.  As you see int the first few lines, I add a mouselistener to CLickCounter(), and add a listener that checks for clicks within the frame.  When I try compiling the program, I get this:

ClickCounter.java:9: error: illegal start of expression

```
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
  ^
```

ClickCounter.java:9: error: illegal start of expression

```
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
         ^
```

ClickCounter.java:9: error: ';' expected

```
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                          ^
```

ClickCounter.java:9: error: ';' expected

```
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                                         ^
```

4 errors

From my understanding, it seems the system doesn't even recognize that line as an event listener.  Did I mess up my syntax somewhere?

Comment: Start with the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html). Not only does it contain working examples but it will show you a better way to create the GUI by using layout managers.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define a method directly within another method in Java. In your case you are defining `mouseClicked()` method directly inside another method (a special method called a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)) `ClickCounter()`.

I suggest picking up a basic [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) before going further. At the very least make yourself comfortable with the syntax.